# Angular Jasmine, unit test case fails when global variable assigned

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a basic unit-test case written for two methods.

```
 it('should populateChartDatasets call getColorCodes', () => {
    component.chartConfig = mockChartConfig;
    spyOn(component, 'getColorCodes');
    component.populateChartDatasets(filteredTreatments, filteredYears);
    expect(component.getColorCodes).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

method `populateChartDatasets` firstly supposed to pick `colorCode` from method `getColorCodes` then push prepared dataset to `chartConfig.data.datasets`.

Everything works pretty good after command `ng serve`

But this test case fails with the error thrown below

```
should populateChartDatasets call getColorCodes FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Inside method `populateChartDatasets`, this line `this.chartConfig.data.datasets.push({})` fails because it seems like methods under `component.chartConfig = mockChartConfig` doesn't wait for this assignment to chartConfig object thats why `data.datasets` thrown as undefined.

I gave `setTimeout 500ms` which solved the problem (at least successful but another error in console thrown)

```
  it('should populateChartDatasets call getColorCodes', () => {
    component.chartConfig = mockChartConfig;
    setTimeout(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'getColorCodes');
      component.populateChartDatasets(filteredTreatments, filteredYears);
      expect(component.getColorCodes).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }, 500);
  });
```

`Spies must be created in a before function or a spec`

How can I make this test passed?

Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/unit-test-template-337ysq?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one issue here, so when you are calling "populateChartDatasets" method internally it depends on "getColorCodes" method to return a string. Without this process "populateChartDatasets" method never completes.
To fix that you can do like this -

```
it('should populateChartDatasets call getColorCodes', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getColorCodes').and.callFake(d => {
      return "#ffffff"
    });
    component.populateChartDatasets(filteredTreatments, filteredYears);
    expect(component.getColorCodes).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```